# Hover over text works on one image but not another. My CodePen is provided

Tags: html, css

I do web development as a hobby, and I'm encountering a problem with a project.

I'm trying to have an image with hover over text, but I can only get it to work on some of my images. I've provided my html and css in [this link](http://codepen.io/Countersnipe/pen/njdEm/). What I'm trying to do is apply the css effects of the 5 images on the top of the page to the image on the bottom left. The only difference is that I want the woman to fade into red (#800000), not white. I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You want the effect to apply to the woman when you hover over the five images?

Comment: No, I want the effect to apply to the woman when you hover over her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
a:hover #redInfo{
  opacity: 0.50;
}
```

You can't use :hover on #rowImage because #redInfo is not a child of the image.

As an aside, consider focusing more on using classes over IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your CSS slightly to include the :hover on the a and then apply styles to the divs (img and info). I've also updated your transitions.

Try applying this after your #firstRow selector and replacing everything below it:

```
#firstRow a { display: block; }

#rowImage{
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1.0s ease;
     -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
        transition: all 1.0s ease;
  opacity: 1;
 }

#redInfo {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:24px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 540px;
  height:753px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #800000;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1.0s ease;
     -o-transition: all 1.0s ease;
        transition: all 1.0s ease;
}

 a:hover > #redInfo { 
opacity: 0.5;
}
```